# DirectX11::Как использовать StructuredBuffer в пиксельном шейдере?

Tags: c++, directx

Я делаю трассировку путей по урокам David Kuri(Перевод статьи - https://habr.com/ru/post/450308/), он создаёт трассировку путей с использованием Unity. Я решил сделать это на DirectX11. Сейчас я остановился на моменте, где он загружает информацию о вертексах с помощью StructuredBuffer. Естественно я попытался сделать то же самое, но вскоре понял, что я не знаю каким образом вообще передавать данные в этот буфер.
Пробовал через константный буфер:

```
struct Vertex
{
float3 Pos;
float3 someValue;
}

cbuffer cModelBuffer
{
Vertex vertices[20];
}
```

Но вот никакие данные из массива структур не считывались(они туда просто не загружались по всей видимости). Да даже если сделать массив из float ничего не работало:

```
cbuffer cModelBuffer
{
float vertices[20];
}
```

В этом случае записывался только [0] элемент массива, а остальные так же не работали. За то работало с vector:

```
cbuffer cModelBuffer
{
vector <float, 20> vertices;
}
```

Но вот со структурами это не работает, в вектор их нельзя поместить.
David Kuri использовал StructuredBuffer, но он заполнял этот буфер через методы Unity. А как это сделать на чистом DirectX11 я без понятия(есть вероятность, что это работает только с ComputeShader). Было бы неплохо если бы вы объяснили мне что к чему, как  сделать буфер структур и загрузить в него информацию с CPU.

Comment: Массив и `vector<>` не являются структурными буферами. На msdn-то заглядывали?

Comment: Так я же всё подробно расписал, я знаю что это не структурные буферы, но так же я знаю, что структурный буфер поможет мне сделать массив из структур, вот только я не знаю как в него загрузить данные(из CPU).

Comment: загружать данные так же как и в константный буфер - создавая буфер вы получаете указатель ID3D11Buffer, который наследует от ID3D11Resource и может обновляться через UpdateSubresource

Comment: А как мне указать, что я хочу записать эти данные именно в эту переменную?(я использую memcpy для загрузки данных в константный буфер).

Comment: при чем тут memcpy? если у вас что-то не работает, то приводите [mcve]

Comment: И плюс я должен же что то привязывать, а не просто обновить буфер. Я тут немного покапал, и нашёл такую штуку: ID3D11UnorderedAccessView. Но теперь проблема в том, что я не могу привязать это к пиксельному шейдеру. Я создаю пременную. и привязываю её к регестру (StructuredBuffer<SomeStructure> some : reguster(u0)), но пишет "buffer requires a 't' register", а этот тип регистра нужен для текстур, но у меня же не текстура... Или есть другой метод привязывать данные к переменной, типа по имени как в openGL?

Comment: чтобы получить UAV для структурного буфера необходимо использовать `RWStructuredBuffer<Type>`

Comment: C RWStructuredBuffer<Type>  реально не выдаёт ошибок, когда я пишу register(u0), но теперь я не знаю, как вообще привязать данные к этой переменной. Какой должен быть тип буфера? Для привязки к вычислытельному шейдеру есть метод CSSetUnorderedAccessViews(), но как мне привязать к пиксильному шейдеру, и что я должен вообще привязывать в таком случае, у меня есть предположение, что это можно как то через shaderResourceView сделать.

Comment: ID3D11DeviceContext::OMSetRenderTargetsAndUnorderedAccessViews

Comment: Короче, я всё сделал, при этом вместо UnorderedAccessViews, я передал буфер как шейдерный ресурс, и всё заработало, и использовал вместо регистра u, регистр t, как для текстур